# Problems with select.select() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, select

Okay, so in some experimentation with sockets and networking, I've set up a very basic chat client/server that runs on Unix flawlessly. Now I'm hitting some errors in the translation to win32. In preface, I understand that select.select() on Windows won't accept socket objects and have (I think) compensated coherently by not passing it the socket object, but the socket number. However, the script still hangs on the select.select() function and I have no idea why. The script only hangs until the server receives a message, after which it allows the client to send messages, however the client can't receive messages from the server, no matter what. I'm trying to troubleshoot these two bugs as best as I can, but my research has turned up dry. Here's the problem code, thanks in advance.

```
while True:
    socket_list.append(s)
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list, [], [], 20)
    if not (read_sockets or write_sockets or error_sockets):
        if afk == False:
            s.send('[Status]: '+str(_user)+' has gone afk.\n')
            sys.stdout.write('\n[+]: You have gone afk.\n')
            afk = True
            prompt()
    for sock in read_sockets:
        print ('Starting for sock in read_sockets') #DEBUG#
        if sock == s:
            print ('Getting here.') #DEBUG#
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                sys.stdout.write('[!]: Disconnected from chat server by server.\n'+W)
                choice = raw_input('[*]: Press Enter to continue.')
                _logic()
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(data)
        else:
            # Rest of the Program (Runs correctly) #
```

Comment: Have you seen http://twistedmatrix.com/?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot to set the sockets non-blocking. Like pretty much all status reporting functions, `select` does not make future guarantees. You also need to handle the case where `read` returns a "would block" indication. You can't rely on `select` to predict the results of future `read` operations.

Comment: In the Unix version, there is no necessity to set the sockets to non-blocking, so I don't necessarily think that's the problem here. Whether I set s.setblocking(0) or don't the script still hangs in the same spot.

Comment: There is a necessity to set the sockets non-blocking. If you don't, you can block. Are you now saying that even if you set the sockets non-blocking, they nevertheless block in a call to `recv`? That would be pretty astonishing.